# Using Raspberry Pi with Powerbank Accumulator

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, battery, power-management

I wanted to power my Raspberry Pi 3B plus some sensors and an additional Huawei modem with a Powerbank. When turned on that's no problem, everything works fine. But I want to measure some enviromental conditions with the Pi over a period of time as long as possible. So I bought a WittyPi wich enables me to set the Pi into a standby mode. This reduces the power consumption dramatically as I've measured. If I connect the Pi to the grid everything works fine, it turns itself on every half hour and send the data it collected to me, but if I use the powerbank it stops supplying energy after a while and the Pi can't boot up again. Do you know how I could solve this? Maybe by switching the circuit in the powerbank with a circuit that doesn't stop the supply? Does such a 'energy controller designed for a Raspberry' exist? And if so do you know any good ones? Or do you have any other idea, I feally don't know what to do.

Comment: I think your Powerbank has power management function that when sensing there is no loading, it will automatically turn off. Many Powerbank has this functionality. The solution is to use plain rechargeable batteries.

Comment: ok thanks.. like six AA batteries in a row do you think that would be enough?

Comment: Rechargeable AA battery is usually 1.2v each.

Comment: 1.2x4 is marginal, but 1.2x5 is over. You may want to have some sort of regulator to limit it to 5v. See [POWER REQUIREMENTS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#topPower) for more details.

Comment: May something like this with 6 batteries, so ir lasts longer http://bit.ly/2EqFn8T